# How Can I Step into OpenCV Source when I debug using QT on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opencv

My Configuration is Mac 10.12.5 + Qt 5.8 + OpenCV2.4.13, I compile the source code using cmake and configure the IDE according to Internet, but I can not step into the OpenCV source code when I debug the OpenCV related code, and I search dozens of web page in Google, it is not any information about this topic, can some specialists or friends tell me?

Comment: You need to install or build debug versions of the libraries.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I compile the opencv as follows: 1. cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local 2.make 3.make install But it still can not step into the opencv source code, can you give me some solutions?

Comment: In addition, I have already build the debug version of opencv 2.4.13, it is larger than version from using Homebrew installing directly, but how to use Qt go through the opencv source code when debugging?